# Casting ArrayList<SomeClass> to ArrayList<SomeInterface>

Tags: java, android

I have 3 classes representing 3 differents things:
`Article`,
`Photos`, and
`Videos`

All 3 things have 2 properties in common: 
A `title` and and `image`.

I have an `interface` called `ImageTitleListItem` that the 3 classes implement.
That `interface` is just a getter/setter for `title` and `image`

I have 3 classes that are `ArrayList`:

```
Articles extends ArrayList<Article>
Photos extends ArrayList<Photo>
Videos extends ArrayList<Video>
```

I have an `ArrayListAdapter` that display a list of those `images` with there `title`.

The constructor of the `ArrayListAdapter` receive `ArrayList<ImageTitleListItem>` as a parameter

When I call it :

```
adapter = new ArrayListAdapter(Articles)
```

I have an error:

```
The constructor ArrayListAdapter(Articles) is undefined
```

That's normal, so i tried to cast it:

```
adapter = new ArrayListAdapter((ArrayList<ImageTitleListItem>)Articles)
```

Now the error is:

```
Cannot cast from Articles to ArrayList<ImageTitleListItem>
```

I'm relativly new to java so there's a trick I'm missing, can somebody help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Post your constructor and relevant parts of your code as a SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ArrayListAdapter constructor needs to be defined as

```
 ArrayListAdapter(List<? extends ImageTitleListItem> list)
```